# Can i take a variable ID in html input tag element?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

i have been trying to add a variable into the html `input` tag but its giving error

```
<% String x = "amol"; %>
<input type="button" name="test" value="Edit" id="<%=x%>"/>
```

this is giving error . please suggest

error --> cannot enter white space in ID 
tool --> Netbeans IDE

Comment: It's probably the `"` before `value`.

Comment: @pawel is probably right, but for future reference: *"this is giving error"* is not useful. Say **what** error you're getting, and from what tool.

Comment: it was a typo .. the error is still there

Comment: Please copy the error, and print it ether in the comments, or edit your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a variable into the html input tag"? You mean displaying this variable value in the input tag or you mean setting the id of the input to the variable value?

Comment: Your code is working fine on my machine.

Comment: it is giving error in Netbeans saying it dosen't allow whitespaces

Comment: @drgPP yes i mean setting the id of the input tag to a variable value

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `"` before value field

Modified Code :

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="Edit" id="<%=x%>"/>
```

Comment: actually that was a typo my bad.. but error is there the " has nothing to do with it

Comment: Can you please copy error in your question?